# Cannot open a folder in google cloud storage gui

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Cannot open a folder ON THE GUI that has a folder name with parenthesis.

Example folder name XYX(MULTI_ABC)/

The workaround for now is to add the folder path on the URL:
example:
https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/project-path/XYX(MULTI_ABC)/?project=google-project

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

HTTP URLs must be encoded for special characters.

For `(` replace with `%28`

For `)` replace with `%29`

For example: https://example.com/my(doc).html

Would be encoded as: https://example.com/my%28doc%29.html

Comment: Thank you. We get this work around. However, our common users click on the folder and it just redirect them to the same page not allowing it to open. This would be troublesome in the long run. Looking for a way for google to fix the code so that users can click on the folder and not have this issue.

Comment: HTTP encoding is mandatory. Google will expect your code to follow the rules. You will have the same problem everywhere.

Comment: I understand that. but this is on google's UI not on our code.'

Comment: Did Google's UI upload those files or another application?

Comment: we have an rsync script to upload the files to the bucket

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and the front end team is working on this but there is no ETA for a solution yet.

Here you have the public issue which you can star if you want to receive status updates and comments.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76202406